# Linq to Entities Left Outer Join with different types

Tags: c#, linq, join, types, entities

I've probably spent 40 hours on this problem so far, I've tried every solution on this site and on google, and I still can't make this work.

I need to left join a table to the results of a previous query, stored in a var. The joining field is a varchar in the table queried for the result in the var, and a bigint (long) in the table being joined. Here is the current attempt, which tells me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." All Entities errors seem like nonsense and lies to me, I assume it's trying to tell me nothing matched, but who knows.

```
        List<reportUser> ru = leaders
        .GroupJoin(db.sweeps,
        a => a.FBID.ToString(),
        s => s.userFBID.First().ToString(),
        (a, matching) => new reportUser
        {
            FBID = a.FBID,
            CurrentPoints = a.CurrentPoints,
            Name = matching.FirstOrDefault().Name,
            Email = matching.FirstOrDefault().email
        }
        ?? new reportUser
        {
            FBID = 0,
            CurrentPoints = 0,
            Name = "",
            Email = ""
        })
        .Select(a => a)
        .ToList();
```

Here's the SQL requested below. I've included the SQL to build the Leaders object as well, all the above is really meant to represent is the last line, which is simply a left join.

select s.name, s.email, b.score, c.score overall
from (
    select a.userfbid, sum(a.pointvalue) score
    from (
        select userfbid, pointvalue
        from l
        left join qa on qa.id = l.qaid
        left join q on q.id = qa.qid
        left join qz on qz.id = q.qzid
        where qa.pointvalue > 0 and qz.cid = 12
        union all
        select fbid userfbid, pointvalue
        from bn
        where date >= '5/9/2011 04:00' and 
              date <= '5/16/2011 04:00'
    ) a
    group by a.userfbid
) b

left join (
    select a.userfbid, sum(a.pointvalue) score
    from (
        select userfbid, pointvalue
        from l
        left join qa on qa.id = l.qaid
        left join q on q.id = qa.qid
        left join qz on qz.id = q.qzid
        where qa.pointvalue > 0
        union all
        select fbid userfbid, pointvalue
        from bn
    ) a
    group by a.userfbid
) c on c.userfbid=b.userfbid

left join s on s.userfbid=b.userfbid
order by score desc

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that in your database `s.userFBID.First()` is never null?

If that's right, then your problem could be in the `FirstOrDefault().Name` type statements - when `FirstOrDefault()` evaluates to `null` then obviously you will get a nullreferenceexception :/

To get around this, try something like:

```
List<reportUser> ru = leaders
        .GroupJoin(db.sweeps,
        a => a.FBID.ToString(),
        s => s.userFBID.First().ToString(),
        (a, matching) => 
        {
            var match = matching.FirstOrDefault();
            return match != null ?
            new reportUser
        {
            FBID = a.FBID,
            CurrentPoints = a.CurrentPoints,
            Name = match.Name,
            Email = match.email
        }
        : new reportUser
        {
            FBID = 0, // a.FBID ?
            CurrentPoints = 0, // a.CurrentPoints ?
            Name = "",
            Email = ""
        }})
        .Select(a => a)
        .ToList();
```

However, I find it a bit hard to do this without seeing the structure of the database... or some sample data

---

Once you've got something working... then I highly recommend you try breaking this down into something more easily understandable - I'm really not sure what's going on here!

Comment: Correct, there should always be a value in sweeps to match any value in the leaders data. Though it is possible to have a value in sweeps with no value corresponding in leaders, but that shouldn't matter.

I've tried using .First() and .FirstOrDefault() both give the error. If I remove that statement, I get an error about being unable to infer type arguments.

Comment: All I want to do is a simple left join here. I don't understand why this much code is even necessary. 

I've got a userFBID field in the Leaders var, and a matching field in db.Sweeps. I simply want to match Name and Email from Sweeps with the data already in Leaders. This would be 10 minutes max in SQL, but I'm at 40 hours in entities, all this complex code I barely understand, and errors I can't fix.

Comment: The code you provided returns the blank set with the values equal to 0 or "" for every record. I'd intended for it only to return that if it got a null, so the next step wouldn't crash. Even though it shouldn't ever actually get a null.

Comment: Ah.... I see... you only want to do a left join... hang on - I'll try another answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple left outer join for you:

```
var query = from l leaders
        join s in db.sweeps on l.FBID equals s.userFBID.First() into joined
        from j in joined.FirstOrDefault()
        select new reportUser
    {
        FBID = l.FBID,
        CurrentPoints = l.CurrentPoints,
        Name = j == null ? string.Empty : j.Name,
        Email = j == null ? string.Empty : j.email
    }
```

If this isn't quite what you are looking for... maybe try posting the SQL for what you actually want.

Comment: As is it wouldn't let me redeclare leaders. I'm assuming you meant to have it say "from l in leaders" so I added that. Now I get an error on "joined.FirstOrDefault()" that says "An expression of type 'web.sweep' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>'. Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.

Comment: I think it's time for you to spend that "10 minutes" writing the SQL

Comment: Added the SQL to my original post